# Preventing PHP/Javascript session abuse in user login page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, session, authentication

Working on my Web Dev degree at a local college and currently in a Website security class.  Got an assignment to make a simple login page, clean up and test username/password (hashed) against a database table, and prevent them from logging in for 5 minutes if they fail 3 attempts.

The technical aspects (using php sessions for example) are no problem, but I am wondering about a more layered defense beyond just checking the hash password against the user/password table.

In the case of tracking the number of failed attempts I was thinking about a session variable that kept a unix-timestamp-and-ip-address as a token to uniquely identify the user and log each failed  attempt.  At the beginning of the fourth reload (after 3 failed attempts) we check the stored session token against a log table.  If we get 3 matches to that token, then we are pretty sure it's the same visitor and can show the visitor "sorry!  try again in 5 minutes" (or similar).

But I am under the impression that closing the browser then opening it again to the website would cause a new session token to be generated.  If a potential attacker is paying attention, he would figure out how circumvent the 3-strikes token check.  A similar problem would apply for being sneaky and storing the token in the browser's Local Storage - a crafty user would know to clear that out.

Am I over-thinking my concern (assuming you can make sense of what I am fishing for)? Is there a practical way of layering the defense of a user login without using something that a savvy user or script kiddie can get around?  Or is a check-hash-against-database sufficient - a sort of KISS principle?

Code snippets (in PHP/Javascript), or favorite article links covering the topic are welcome and appreciated, along with any constructive commentary.  Thanks for your time!  -Jimm

Comment: sessions are invariably cookie based. block the session cookie, or delete it ever few attempts, and you can just keep hammering on the server. you have to block IPs, there's no other semi-reliable method.

Comment: good question, I hope someone has a good answer for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you said, client side scripts or variables won't prevent this type of behavior, as a savvy attacker can easily get past these sorts of defenses.  It becomes more of an annoyance for a forgetful user than for an attacker.  You need to store this information in a database.  Also, simply storing in IP information and timestamps isn't reliable, as someone can easily request a new IP address.  Again, this is just another pain for the user, and not for the attacker.

Like another answer here, the best way to prevent multiple log ins is to prevent that user's *account* from being able to attempt more passwords.  The security design in this is to prevent an attacker, who knows a particular username, from being able to brute-force the password. However, this does nothing to prevent a user from using bad credentials, as a wrong username will not be logged as an attempt.  Also, this allows a user to shutdown another users profile just by making bad attempts using their username.  This is where you would need to log IP information with username information, but it involves detecting a different IP address from what they usually use, and prompting them to make sure that this device is trustworthy (or something along those lines).  It definitely seems like it would be out of scope for your question, but feel free to tackle it if you feel up to it.

The best way, I feel, is to make a script that whenever a user hits the "submit" button to log in, you check your database for a previous time stamp, and the number of log in attempts (which should be 0 after a reset).  Every time a user tries a log in with bad credentials, update the time stamp and # of log in attempts.  After so many attempts, send a "true" value or something to the database to show that this account is locked for a certain duration, which (for a 5 minute penalty) would be the time stamp+5minutes.  Whenever a user attempts a new log in, if that penalty time stamp has not yet happened, it denies them a log in attempt.  The time stamp could also be used to see if a user is hitting your page with many log in attempts at once.  Simply check if the current time stamp is relatively close to the old one, and deny the attempt if it is.

Answer (score 0):

You lock the *account*, not the user. That's what most sites do, and is foolproof.